# Upload file with progressbar in the same page with struts2

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, struts2, progress-bar

I need to upload a very heavy file and that's why the progress bar on the same page. I have searched a lot and the `execAndWait interceptor` does not work for me because it puts the progress bar on an intermediate page. So I developed my own idea, which is the following:

**subirArchivoNomina.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sb" uri="/struts-bootstrap-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <s:head />
    <sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="cupertino" />
    <sb:head/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vista/css/subirArchivos.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vista/js_libs/bootstrap-filestyle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vista/js/subirArchivoNomina.js"></script>
    <title><s:property value="%{getText('conciliacion.de.nomina')}"/></title>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form id="form" action="procesarNomina" cssClass="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <s:file type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonBefore="true" id="fileNomina" name="fileNomina" data-text="%{getText('examinar')}" ></s:file>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <sj:progressbar id="progressbarchange" value="21" onChangeTopics="mychangetopic"/> <br /> 
            <sj:a href="#" onClickTopics="myclicktopic" cssClass="buttonlink ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh"></span>change value</sj:a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <s:submit id="btn_subir" button="true" value="%{getText('subir.archivos')}"  class="simple ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget"   />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**subirArchivoNomina.js**

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(":file").filestyle();
    $("#btn_subir").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("llegue");
        idInterval=setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "corriendo",
                //data: formData,
                type: "POST",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data);//siempre es 0//always is 0
                $("#progressbarchange").progressbar( 'value' , parseInt( data ) );
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert("error\njqXHR=" + jqXHR + "\nstatus=" + textStatus + "\nerror=" + errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }).always(function(dataORjqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_ORerrorThrown) {
                //alert( "complete" );
            });
        }, 500*10);
        var formData = new FormData();
        var archivo = document.getElementsByName("fileNomina");
        formData.append("fileNomina", archivo[0].files[0]);
        console.log("action="+$("#form").attr("action"));
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#form").attr("action"),
            data: formData,
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            clearInterval(idInterval);
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error\njqXHR=" + jqXHR + "\nstatus=" + textStatus + "\nerror=" + errorThrown);
        }).always(function(dataORjqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_ORerrorThrown) {
            //alert( "complete" );
        });
    });
    $.subscribe('mychangetopic', function(event,data){
        console.log("progressbar= "+$("#progressbarchange").progressbar('option', 'value'));
    }); 
    $.subscribe('myclicktopic', function(event,data) {
        $("#progressbarchange").progressbar( 'value' , parseInt( Math.random() * ( 90 ) ) );
    });
});
```

Here is the main idea: from javascript I execute an action `corriendo` which will tell me what percentage(porcentaje) has been uploaded from the file, that is why it is in a `setInterval` because it must be executed periodically, then with another ajax I upload the file.

**struts.xml**

```
//...
<action name="procesarNomina" class="mx.unam.patronato.conciliacion.actions.SubirNominaAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">52428800</param><!--  50 MB por archivo-->
                <param name="allowedTypes">text/plain, application/rtf, application/msword</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            <result name="success" type="tiles">.subirNominaSinMenu</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">.subirNominaSinMenu</result>
        </action>
        <action name="corriendo" class="mx.unam.patronato.conciliacion.actions.SubirNominaAction" method="getStreamPorcentaje">
            <result type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">text/plain</param>
            </result>
        </action>
//...
```

**subirNominaAction.java**

```
public class SubirNominaAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware,ServletRequestAware {
    private SessionMap<String, Object> sessionMap;
    private String fechaInicio,fechaFin;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private List<File> fileNomina=new ArrayList<File>();
    private List<String> fileNominaContentType=new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> fileNominaFileName=new ArrayList<String>();
    private Double porcentaje;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    public SubirNominaAction() {
        setPorcentaje(0.0);
    }
    //getters y setters
    public String getStreamPorcentaje() {
        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(getPorcentaje().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        //System.out.println("entre:"+fechaInicio);
        System.out.print("\n\n---------------------------------------");
        int i=0;
        for (File file : fileNomina){
            double tamanoArchivo=(int)file.length();
            double bytesLine=0;
            int k=0;
            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file.toURI()), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)){
                for(String line : (Iterable<String>) lines::iterator){
                    bytesLine+=line.getBytes().length;
                    setPorcentaje(bytesLine/tamanoArchivo*100);
                    //System.out.println(getPorcentaje());
                    System.out.println(k+"\t"+line);
                    //System.out.println(line.getBytes().length);
                    k++;
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print("\nFile ["+i+"] ");
            System.out.print("; name:"         + fileNominaFileName.get(i));
            System.out.print("; contentType: " + fileNominaContentType.get(i));
            System.out.print("; length: "      + file.length());
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("\n---------------------------------------\n");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

In `subirNominaAction.java` I read the total of the file and then I read line by line to calculate the `percentage(porcentaje)` that it takes. The file uploads correctly and the `percentage(porcentaje)` is also calculated correctly, I know by console impressions that I made. **The problem is that in the** `setInterval` **that declares that it invokes the action** `corriendo` **and that this in turn invokes** `getStreamPercentaje`, **it always returns 0**. And that is the value I need to update the progress bar:

```
console.log(data);//siempre es 0//always is 0
$("#progressbarchange").progressbar( 'value' , parseInt( data ) );
```

Does anyone have any idea how to correct it? It seems that each time the action class is invoked a new instance is created and it does not use the one that is already running.

Or in his defect somebody has some example on how to use the `interceptor execAndWait` to use it with a progressbar in the same page?.

Answer (score 0):

A upload progressbar has nothing to do with struts. It's more a javascript thing you have to handle on the browser side. Normally struts will get the full uploaded file **after** the server has received it completly. So your method will always return 0 because the file does yet not exist.

With your current ajax request you still upload the file at once and you don't get any feedback during the upload process.

So, you need some sort of javascript, which can tell you about the current status of the upload. There are libraries like [this](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) or even (new modern) javascript functions like the [XMLHttpRequest advanced features](https://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) that could help you. It is even possible to chunk the file you wish to upload ([jquery plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads)), but I never have tested this with struts.

Hope the links help you in anyway.

Comment: The issue here is that each line of the file will carry an additional processing which implies more execution time, that is why I need to obtain the advance percentage on the server side.